# Checkbox enabling inactive fields

Tags: javascript

I was just wondering if it is possible to enable an inactive field by checking a checkbox by using javascript? For example the following the text field is initially disabled but if you check the checkbox the text field enables and allows you to enter a value

```
<input type="checkbox" name="enable" id="enable">

<input type="text" id="name" name="name">
```

I have done some searching but I cant seem to find something that works well and I am fairly new to javascript so any help or a nudge in the right direction would be great.

Comment: its no good repeating question, as you already have the same question posted before..!

Comment: In  that i was looking more for if a text field is clicked on then it enables other field, i just worded it all wrongly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
window.onload=function(){
    document.getElementById('enable').onchange=function(){
        var txt = document.getElementById('name');
        txt.disabled = !this.checked;
    };
};
```

[DEMO1](http://jsfiddle.net/8RTc2/2/) and [DEMO 2](http://jsfiddle.net/8RTc2/3/).

Comment: You can reduce that to `document.getElementById('name').disabled = !this.checked`. http://jsfiddle.net/elclanrs/8RTc2/1/

Comment: @elclanrs, Ah! That's nice, Thanks.

Comment: if i want the checkbox to enable more than 1 text field when it is checked how would i do that in the same function?

Comment: @francis, You need a loop then.

Comment: what sort of loop would i need to use?

Comment: @francis, [Check this](http://jsfiddle.net/8RTc2/3/).

Comment: Ah a for loop, seemed to work fine on your demo but when i tried it, no luck. The fields still stay disabled, for your "var d = document.getElementById('txts').childNodes;" does the Id have to be the same as Id as the text fields?

Comment: @francis, did you check the HTML too ?

Comment: oh my mistake! I forgot the <div>, thanks so much for the help!

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>**[Working FIDDLE Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mojtaba/DCMGL/)**</kbd>

It's possible. Consider the following HTML markup:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="enable" id="enable" />
<input type="text" id="name" name="name" disabled="disabled" />
```

And this JavaScript:

```
// get checkbox element
var checkbox = document.getElementById('enable');

// get textbox element
var field = document.getElementById('name');

// whenever user click on checkbox
checkbox.onclick = function () {
    // get check status of checkbox
    var checked = this.checked;

    // enable or disable textbox based on checked status
    field.disabled = ! checked;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Using checkbox control multiple input fields.See this [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cke93/).

```
$("body").on("click","#enable",function(){
    if($(this).filter(":checked").length>0)
        $("#fields input").removeAttr("disabled");
    else{
        $("#fields input").attr("disabled",true);
    }
})
```